# Floating action button ionic app

Tags: android, ionic-framework, material-design, floating-action-button

I want to add a floating action button into my app and whenever I add it, my localhost seems to show it, but when debugging it on my phone it just says 'add' the value to give it the + symbol.

I only import in my index.html

```
<link href="lib/ionic/css/ionic.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Itim|Roboto" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.getmdl.io/1.2.1/material.indigo-pink.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../mdl/material.min.css">
<script src="../mdl/material.js"></script>
<script defer src="https://code.getmdl.io/1.2.1/material.min.js"></script>    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">




<ion-content>
    <ion-list>
      <ion-item ng-repeat="task in tasks" class="item-icon-right" ng-class="{complete: task.completed}" ng-click="task.completed = !task.completed">
        {{task.title}}
        <i class="icon ion-android-create"></i>
        <ion-option-button class="button-assertive" ng-click="tasks.splice($index, 1)">Delete</ion-option-button>
        <ion-option-button class="button-energized" ng-click="edit(task)">Edit</ion-option-button>
        </ion-item>
        <!--<ion-option-button ng-click="showAlert()">Alert</ion-option-button>-->
      <!--<ion-item>
        <select name="singleSelect" ng-model="data.headerColor">
          <option value="bar-positive">Blue</option>
          <option value="bar-calm">Light blue</option>
          <option value="bar-balanced">Green</option>
          <option value="bar-energized">Yellow</option>
          <option value="bar-assertive">Red</option>
          <option value="bar-royal">Purple</option>
          <option value="bar-dark">Black</option>
        </select><br>
      </ion-item>-->

    </ion-list>

      <!-- Real floating action button, fixed. It will not scroll with the content -->
      <ion-fab top right edge>
        <button ion-fab mini><ion-icon name="add"></ion-icon></button>
        <ion-fab-list>
          <button ion-fab><ion-icon name="logo-facebook"></ion-icon></button>
          <button ion-fab><ion-icon name="logo-twitter"></ion-icon></button>
          <button ion-fab><ion-icon name="logo-vimeo"></ion-icon></button>
          <button ion-fab><ion-icon name="logo-googleplus"></ion-icon></button>
        </ion-fab-list>
      </ion-fab>

      <ion-fab right bottom>
        <button ion-fab color="light"><ion-icon name="arrow-dropleft"></ion-icon></button>
        <ion-fab-list side="left">
          <button ion-fab><ion-icon name="logo-facebook"></ion-icon></button>
          <button ion-fab><ion-icon name="logo-twitter"></ion-icon></button>
          <button ion-fab><ion-icon name="logo-vimeo"></ion-icon></button>
          <button ion-fab><ion-icon name="logo-googleplus"></ion-icon></button>
        </ion-fab-list>
      </ion-fab>




  </ion-content>
```

Comment: Please share your code for adding the action button

Comment: Are you using the Ionic floating action button components? http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/components/#fabs

Comment: @amuramoto  and User528491 I add the code from my content, but even with the Ionic components it says that the attribute ion-fab is not allowed..

Comment: @Lucafraser Not sure what you mean by 'it says that the attribute ion-fab is not allowed.' Can you post the error message you're seeing?

Comment: I figured it out! I am using Ionic V1 but using the fab is only possible when using Ionic v2.